# Create a remove event listener and add event listener for this function

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

I need to make this function have the ability to have an add event listener and remove event listener

canvas2 was $('canvas') but i changed it to make it easier to use

```
canvas2.mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
```

because this does not have an event listener

Comment: What? What do you mean by "*have*"?

Comment: I don't have any idea what you're asking.

Comment: i need the function to be add event listener becuase it is a drawing application so when the function has been used the function needs to be disengaged but with the thing i have at the moment it willk continuously run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess: You want

```
canvas2.on("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
…
canvas2.off("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
```

With the unnecessary anonymous function you did not have a reference to the actual passed listener, so you could not remove it any more.

> when the function has been used the function needs to be disengaged

You might also consider using [`.one("mousedown", handleMouseDown)`](http://api.jquery.com/one/), then.

Comment: i got this function to work thanks :D the code here was slightly off, for the .off function it should look like this canvas2.off("mousedown"); just removed that event listener, but it got me to where i need so thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to say either

```
canvas2.onmousedown=function(e){
     handleMouseDown(e);
});
```

or

```
canvas2.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){
     handleMouseDown(e);
});
```